# Update UILabel inside UITableViewCell without full page refresh using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uilabel

I have a particular conundrum where I need a specific `UILabel` inside a `UITableViewCell` to update every minute. Currently, every minute, the whole entire cell refreshes and displays beneath the previous one, see below, all I want to do is refresh that `UILabel` called `watchTime`:

[image]

Here's my tableView where I initialize the watch time minute count from the model

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "watchTimeCell", for: indexPath) as! WatchTimeCell
    if userModel.count > indexPath.row {
        //this is the value i want to update
        cell.watchTime.text = "\(String(describing: userModel[indexPath.row].watchTime!))"
    }
    return cell
}
```

And here's how I update my cell currently:

```
@objc func updateCounting(){
    watchTime += 1
    if watchTime % 60 == 0 {
        let userRef = Database.database().reference().child("users").child(uid!).child("watchTime")
        userRef.runTransactionBlock({ (currentData: MutableData) -> TransactionResult in
            let newValue: Int

            if let existingValue = (currentData.value as? NSNumber)?.intValue {
                newValue = existingValue + 1
            } else {
                newValue = 1
            }

            currentData.value = NSNumber(value: newValue)

            //this is the line where I reload the cell

            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                self.watchTableView.reloadData()
            })

            return TransactionResult.success(withValue: currentData)
        })
        watchTime = 0
        }
    }
```

What's the best way to go about this? Thanks!

EDIT: Added `numberOfRowsInSection`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return userModel.count
}
```

Comment: how many cells you have? I'm asking because maybe stackview would suit your need better

Comment: FYI - never use `String(describing:)` to show a value to a user. It is only for debugging purposes.

Comment: @Honey just one, still learning and testing my knowledge with tableView!

Comment: @JordanLewallen is there somewhere else that userModel.count is getting incremented?  This would likely be the reason that on watchtableView.reloadData() is showing an additional cell after 1min mark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're doing is essentially correct for a table view. You update the *model* and call `reload` to propagate that thru `cellForRowAt` to the table view. You could, in this situation, save some overhead by calling `reloadRows(at:with:)` so as to reload only the one cell.

Except...

You *have* only one cell. But a one-cell table view is ridiculous. What's its purpose? To make the interface scrollable? Then just make a scroll view. Now you can update the label directly.

Comment: yea I had 3 proto cells at one point and wanted to test my knowledge to figure out how to update something specific inside a cell. To make that UILabel refresh itself on a scrollview I would simply call `watchTime.reloadData()` inside that DispatchQueue? or is there a different method call to use?

Comment: There is no `reloadData` with a label. A label has no data source mechanism; it doesn't need one. You would just set the label's text, kaboom.

Answer (score 0):

I would create that one cell, with a reference to it in the ViewController that is holding the tableView.

```
let mainCell = WatchTimeCell()
```

Inside the WatchTimeCell class I would add a public func to update the time count

```
public func updateTimeCountLabel(_ count: Int) {
 self.nameOfLabel.text = "\(count)"

}
```

Then within the updateCounting() I would call the updateTimeCountLabel inside the WatchTimeCell.

```
self.mainCell.updateTimeCountLabel(newValue)
```

But there is something happening within the numberOfRowsForSection, could you post that?

Comment: interested to test this out, I've added `numberOfRowsForSection()` for you